# WinForms Checkbox button image alignment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a toggle button inside C# WinForms application. Now I have managed to make the toggle button look and feel with the suggestion from my previous post.

Now the problem is, I'm not able to centre align the images from my `ImageList` properly on the button, so its showing some of the back colors on its edges. Please see the below images for clear view.

[image: Toggle state 1]
[image: Toggle state 2]

How can I get rid of this white edges?

Things tried so far:

1. `FlatAppearance` of the Button is set to Flat.
2. Tried with `Transparent` background color but that didn't work.
3. `ImageAlign` is set to `MiddleCenter`.

**Code generated by WinForms designer**

```
  // 
  // checkBox1
  // 
  this.checkBox1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
  this.checkBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
  this.checkBox1.CausesValidation = false;
  this.checkBox1.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
  this.checkBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
  this.checkBox1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
  this.checkBox1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
  this.checkBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
  this.checkBox1.ImageIndex = 0;
  this.checkBox1.ImageList = this.imageList1;
  this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 178);
  this.checkBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
  this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
  this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 62);
  this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
  this.checkBox1.Text = "Sample Button";
  this.checkBox1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
  this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1);
```

**Update:** I'v managed to get rid of these white edges by reducing button size 1px (both x, y) from the image size. Image size is: 99x63, Button size 98x62. But I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: what code does winform designer generates for Sample Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple. Choose therese settings:

```
checkBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
checkBox1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

// make all four (!) BackColors transparent!
checkBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
checkBox1.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
checkBox1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Note that with FlatStyle.Flat the checkboxbutton reserves 8 horizontal pixels, 6 at the left and 2 at the right edge and will cut off 8 pixels from your Image unless you enlarge it like so:

```
checkBox1.Size = new Size(imageList1.ImageSize.Width + 8, imageList1.ImageSize.Height);
```

Now all pixels are displayed, however the control is not visibly left aligned until you move it to the left by 6 pixels!

Looking at your example both issues are probably not important, though, but sometimes they are..

Comment: I think you need to change __all four__ BackColors to Transparent.

Comment: Please see my comment on the right sizes and alignment!